# How to find a specific XML node and delete its parent node?

Tags: xml, vb6, xml-parsing

I have an XML file that reads like this

```
<abc>
  <ab>value</ab>
  <aa>time</aa>
  <ac>money</ac>
</abc>
<abc>
  <ab>right</ab>
  <aa>left</aa>
  <ac>straight</ac>
</abc>
```

What i want is that i am able to find the node which has a value "left" and then delete its parent node so that what i get at last is

```
<abc>
  <ab>value</ab>
  <aa>time</aa>
  <ac>money</ac>
</abc>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Invalid XML, you can only have one top-level element!  That said you could write code to manually parse this pseudo-XML I suppose.

Comment: Hey Bob. I had only written here a psuedo xml. Actually, i needed to find a specific node and delete it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was corrected to valid XML by adding a document element:

```
<doc>
    <abc>
        <ab>value</ab>
        <aa>time</aa>
        <ac>money</ac>
    </abc>
    <abc>
        <ab>right</ab>
        <aa>left</aa>
        <ac>straight</ac>
    </abc>
</doc>
```

You could do something like:

```
Dim DOM As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim Node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode

Set DOM = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
With DOM
    .async = False
    .preserveWhiteSpace = True
    If .Load("sample.xml") Then
        .setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
        Set Node = .selectSingleNode("//*[.='left']")
        If Not Node Is Nothing Then
            .documentElement.removeChild Node.parentNode
            On Error Resume Next
            Kill "sample.xml"
            On Error GoTo 0
            .save "sample.xml"
            MsgBox "Done, saved as sample.xml"
        Else
            MsgBox "No ""left"" found"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Load failed!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine _
             & CStr(.parseError.errorCode) & " " _
             & .parseError.reason
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Hi, Even i was using the same logic using selectSingleNode. The difference was that i was using selectSingleNode("left"). the extra ("//*[.='left']") did the trick for me. If it doesn't bother you much can you explain the difference. Thanks Bob for your help. :)

Comment: An XPath expert may laugh at what I used, I'd prefer a better answer that worked myself.  AFAIK what this says is something like "(//) descending recursively from this point, (*) any tags, ([]) filter for nodes where, (.) the node itself, (='left') has its text equal to 'left'" but I could be wrong.

Comment: Oh, and I think your simpler XPath expression was saying something like "the child node with tag name 'left'."  Perhaps some kind soul will post a link to an XPath reference that isn't written from the point of view of somebody trying to *implement* an XPath parser but *actually use XPath*.